# How to create 6 digit OTP with 2 digits and 4 alphabets?

Tags: php, shuffle

I have a script which generates 6 character One Time Password (OTP).

Here is the code:-

```
$seed = str_split('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.'0123456789'); // and any other characters
shuffle($seed); // probably optional since array_is randomized; this may be redundant
$rand = '';
foreach (array_rand($seed, 6) as $k) 
    $rand .= $seed[$k];
$feedID = $rand;
```

Now, due to shuffling procedure, currently all 6 can be digits, all 6 can be alphabets.
I want min and max 2 mandatory digits.

**How can I do that?**

Comment: Does position of Digits are fix like starting or in end

Comment: No fixed position. @SunilPachlangia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my take on it:

```
// Create a string of all alpha characters and randomly shuffle them
$alpha   = str_shuffle('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');

// Create a string of all numeric characters and randomly shuffle them
$numeric = str_shuffle('0123456789');

// Grab the 4 first alpha characters + the 2 first numeric characters
$code = substr($alpha, 0, 4) . substr($numeric, 0, 2);

// Shuffle the code to get the alpha and numeric in random positions
$code = str_shuffle($code);
```

If you want the possibility to have any character more than once, change the two first lines (quick and dirty):

```
// Let's repeat this string 4 times before shuffle, since we need 4 characters
$alpha   = str_shuffle(str_repeat('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 4));

// Let's repeat this string 2 times before shuffle, since we need 2 numeric characters
$numeric = str_shuffle(str_repeat('0123456789', 2));
```

Not saying that this is the best way of doing it, but it's simple, without loops and/or arrays. :)

Comment: This was exactly my thought. :)

Comment: This takes every char only once.  `ADB24D` cant happen here.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions - Updated with an alternative example, for that case.

Comment: OK, nice. Just noted it. :)

Comment: Excellent. I always forget about `str_shuffle`.

Answer (score 1):

One more option.

Not saying that this is the best way of doing it, but it's simple, *with* loops and arrays. `;)`

```
foreach ([4 => range('A', 'Z'), 2 => range(0, 9)] as $n => $chars) {
    for ($i=0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        $otp[] = $chars[array_rand($chars)];
    }
}
shuffle($otp);
$otp = implode('', $otp);
```

Comment: This was a nice one too. I always forget about `range()`. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $seed = str_split('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
 $seed2= str_split('0123456789');
 $rand = [];
 for($i=mt_rand(1,2);$i<=2;$i++){
   shuffle($seed2);
   $rand[]=$seed2[0];     
 }
 while(count($rand)!=6){
  shuffle($seed);
  $rand[]=$seed[0];
 }
 shuffle($rand);
 print $feedID = implode('',$rand);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use random() also to genarate the string with num + letters.[LINK](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
        $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }
        return $randomString;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you

```
    function generateRandomString($length = 10,$char_len=4,$numbre_len=2) {

    $characters = '0123456789';
    $characters2='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
  $charactersLength2 = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i <$char_len ; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters2[rand(0, $charactersLength2 - 1)];
    }
  for ($i = 0; $i <$numbre_len ; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }

   $shuffled = str_shuffle($randomString);
    return $shuffled;
}


 $length=7;
$char_len=6;
$numbre_len=1;
echo generateRandomString($length,$char_len,$numbre_len);
```

This function may help to generate dynamic random otp which you want.